# How to increase max hot keys per interval?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using Auto Hot Key to invert the scrolling on my Mac while running bootcamp. It makes it easier when I switch between OS's.

Only problem is.....the program keeps telling me it `has received 71 hot keys in the past 1700ms.`

How can I increase this number or disable this? I don't plan on using the hot keys program for anything except the scrolling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation says that changing [#MaxHotkeysPerInterval](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MaxHotkeysPerInterval.htm) should solve your problem, for example:

```
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 200
```

Comment: That SEEMS to have worked! Note I had to go to `File` -> `Edit Script`, and add it there. Then I had to go to `File` -> `Reload Script`.