# #MaxHotKeysPerInterval On Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Pretty much same question as the one on this thread

[How to increase max hot keys per interval?](https://superuser.com/questions/492448/how-to-increase-max-hot-keys-per-interval)

^In that one, the person who asked the question said it worked but they had to go to Files>Edit Script.. what I want to know is where they saw the option for Files so that I may do so.

To my understanding I just need to follow the answer there, however I don't know HOW to get to that page, I have no knowledge of the scripts offered online or how to use scripts in the first place. I just want to know where I can find the text file where "#MaxHotKeysPerInterval 70" is so I can do it. When I hit the AutoHotKey icon it tells me it has those scripts running, and hitting the AutoHotKey help leads me nowhere. Hopefully someone can understand how computer-dumb I am and give me a clear and concise answer a 10 year old could understand.

Answer (score 3):

There is no line `#MaxHotKeysPerInterval 70`, this is a default. To change it, you have to **add** the line `#MaxHotKeysPerInterval 200` on top of the script causing the error.

To do so is quite easy: Every script you run creates a green icon with a white H inside in the tray (the lower right part of your screen). Right click on this icon, then left click on "Edit this script". A *Notepad* window will open, containing the code for the script. Copy the line  `#MaxHotKeysPerInterval 200` and paste it on top of the script (it has to stand on a line on its own). Then save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>), and close the window.

The last part is reloading your (modified) script: Right click on its tray icon, and choose "Reload this script".